# How to change status of process from the Running to Zombile or Create process with Zombie status

Tags: python, command-line

How do I change the process status from Running to Zombie or create a process with Zombie status?

I am writing a script to kill the Zombie process during the script.

**1. How to get target Pid's**

`SCRIPT_RUNNING_CMD = "ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -v $0 | grep custom.py"`

`status = os.system(settings_mod.SCRIPT_RUNNING_CMD +" >> "+tmpfile)`

I parsed the `tmpfile` to get the Target process PID's

**2. Get Process status from the `psutil`**

```
import psutil
p = psutil.process(123)
p.status
```

How do I forcefully change the process status?

Answer (score 0):

You can not kill zombie processes because they are already dead. You can only disappear them by killing their parent processes. If you want to create one for testing purposes, you can do it in `bash` like:

```
$ (makezombie=$BASHPID && ( kill -STOP $makezombie ))
```

Comment: for example `$ (makezombie=$7363 && ( kill -STOP $makezombie ))` correct?

Comment: $BASHPID is an internal variable that gives the process id of the current instance of bash. You can connect to another terminal session then run the above command. After this, **defunct** process can be seen using `$ ps -ef |grep bash`

Comment: 7363 is my python process, when I run above command , this is kill the process and I get status as Stopped.